# Trying to implement my own vector class, keep getting "undefined reference" error

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement my own vector class as an exercise of the book Accelerated C++, but I'm getting these errors and I can't figure out how to fix them:

C:\MinGW\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2........\include\c++\3.4.2\bits\allocator.h||undefined reference to `vec::create()'|

::~vec()]+0x43):C:\MinGW\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2........\include\c++\3.4.2\bits\allocator.h||undefined reference to `vec::uncreate()'|

I'm using code::blocks and both files are in the same project, so I'm pretty sure it's not a linking issue.

Here is the vec.h file

```
#ifndef VEC_H
#define VEC_H

#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>

template <class T> class vec{
public:
    typedef T* iterator;
    typedef const T* const_iterator;
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef T value_type;

    vec(){
        create();
    }

    explicit vec(size_type n, const T& val = T()){
        create(n,val);
    }

    vec(const vec& v){
        create(v.begin(), v.end());
    }

    ~vec(){
        uncreate();
    }

    size_type size() const{
        return avail - data;
    }

    T& operator[](size_type i){
        return data[i];
    }

    const T& operator[](size_type i) const{
        return data[i];
    }

    vec& operator = (const vec&);

    void push_back(const T& t){
        if(avail == limit)
            grow();
        unchecked_append(t);
    }

    iterator begin(){ return data; }
    const_iterator begin() const{ return data; }

    iterator end(){ return avail; }
    const_iterator end() const{ return avail; }

private:
    iterator data; //first element
    iterator avail;//one past the last available element
    iterator limit;//one past the total allocated memory

    //facilities for memory allocation

    std::allocator<T> alloc; //object to handle memory allocation

    //allocate and initialize the underlying array
    void create();
    void create(size_type, const T&);
    void create(const_iterator, const_iterator);

    //destroy the elements in the array and free the memory
    void uncreate();

    //support functions for push_back
    void grow();
    void unchecked_append(const T&);
};

#endif // VEC_H
```

and the vec.cpp file

```
#include "vec.h"

template <class T> vec<T>& vec<T>::operator=(const vec& rhs){
    //check for self-assignment
    if(&rhs != this){
        //free the array in the left-hand side
        uncreate();

        //copy elements from the right-hand to the left-hand side
        create(rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
    }

    return *this;
}

template <class T> void vec<T>::create(){
    data = avail = limit = 0;
}

template <class T> void vec<T>::create(size_type n, const T& val){
    data = alloc.allocate(n);
    limit = avail = data+n;
    uninitialized_fill(data, limit, val);
}

template <class T> void vec<T>::create(const_iterator i, const_iterator j){
    data = alloc.allocate(j-i);
    limit = avail = uninitialized_copy(i, j, data);
}

template <class T> void vec<T>::uncreate(){
    if(data){
        //destroy in reverse order the objects that were constructed
        iterator it = avail;
        while(it != data)
            destroy(--it);

        //return all the space that was allocated
        alloc.deallocate(data, limit-data);
    }

    data = limit = avail = 0;
}

template <class T> void vec<T>::grow(){
    //when growing, allocate twice as much space as currently in use
    size_type new_size = max(2*(limit-data), ptrdiff_t(1));

    //allocate new space and copy existing elements to the new space
    iterator new_data  = alloc.allocate(new_size);
    iterator new_avail = uninitialized_copy(data, avail, new_data);

    //return the old space
    uncreate();

    //reset pointers to point to the newly allocated space
    data  = new_data;
    avail = new_avail;
    limit = data + new_size;
}

//assumes avail points to allocated, but uninitialized space
template <class T> void vec<T>::unchecked_append(const T& val){
    alloc.construct(avail++, val);
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your class is a template you need to put the implementation into the header file, not in a .cpp file as the full class definition needs to be visible to the compiler during compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Templates must be defined in every translation unit that uses them; by putting the function definitions into a source file, they are only defined in one unit, giving errors if you try to use them in another.

Move the function definitions into the header, after the class definition.